# add excel range after specific text in word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, range, paste

From within excel, I want to copy a cellrange to a specific position in an excisting word-document, using a macro. The position should be right after a unique word in that word-document.

Here are the 2 files: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoL8lLA69BSAiu0z6xdsvRK7IzyC9A?e=R8E5ex  (excelsheet with and without macro)

Here is the excel macro:

```
Sub test()
'
' test Macro
'
' Sneltoets: Ctrl+Shift+P


Worksheets("artikelen").Range("A2:I6").Copy


Dim wdapp As Object, wddoc As Object
Dim strdocname As String

On Error Resume Next
Set wdapp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    Err.Clear
    Set wdapp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End If
wdapp.Visible = True
strdocname = "C:\temp\test1.docx"
If Dir(strdocname) = "" Then
    MsgBox "The document " & strdocname & vdCrLf & " is not found at the defined location.", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

wdapp.Activate

If wddoc Is Nothing Then
    Set wddoc = wdapp.Documents.Open(strdocname)
End If


Set myRange2 = wddoc.Content
myRange2.Find.Execute FindText:="searchtext"
wddoc.Range.Paste



wddoc.Save
' wdapp.Quit

Set wddoc = Nothing
Set wdapp = Nothing
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

++++++++

The only thing that doesn't work is the pasting of the excel-range after the word: 'searchtext' in my word-doc. 
It's the piece of code:

```
Set myRange2 = wddoc.Content
    myRange2.Find.Execute FindText:="searchtext"
    wddoc.Range.Paste
```

... that is not working

I feel like I'm 99% there... Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. rgrds, Richard

Comment: Please include sample data as part of your question and not an external link: it makes the question useless once the links go dead. Not to mention many people won't download files from unknown sources. Also, what is the expected result in Word? A table or a bunch of text following the found word?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct.

The paste is not working correctly as you are pasting into `wddoc.Range` which is the entire document. You should be pasting into `myRange2`, but only if the text you are searching for is found.

Fortunately a successful find will set `myRange2` to the range of the found text. Changing your code as below should make the paste work for you:

```
  If myRange2.Find.Execute(FindText:="searchtext") Then
    myRange2.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    myRange2.Paste
  End If
```

Comment: @tony1968 Please thank someone who provides an answer on Stack Overflow by clicking the checkmark at the left of the answer. This marks it as "the" answer, which helps others. It also awards the contributor site points (reputation).